# PostgreSQL failover with two standby servers

Tags: postgresql

I have one master and two standby servers setup via Streaming Replication(postgresql 9.0.5). Now if master fails i bring one of the standby out of recovery mode by creating trigger file. Now will the secondary standby follow the new master assuming i fix recovery_target_timeline = latest in recovery.conf file?

Answer (score 2):

No, because the new master doesn't know it has a slave. And the new slave doesn't know it has a new master. You have to change the corresponding configuration files to get the required situation.

Check [repmgr](http://www.repmgr.org/) as well, maybe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, this answer is correct, and also makes a helpful suggestion.